What is the area of this triangle?
Setup

Take two parallel lines separated by a distance $h$, now take two distinct points $p$ and $q$ on any one of the lines separated by a distance $b$. Draw a perpendicular from point $p$ to the other parallel line and take a point $r$ on this line such that it is a distance $x$ away from the intersection point of the perpendicular and this parallel line. Now, the area of the $\Delta pqr$ is given by:
$$\text{area}(\Delta pqr) = \frac{1}{2}\times{b}\times{h}$$
Question
Since the area of the triangle does not depend on $x$, the area should remain constant as $x$ varies. But, as $x$ approaches $\infty$ the angle $\angle qpr$ should approach $0$, right? If so, the line $pr$ will become parallel to $pq$ and never intersect the second parallel line which will cause the area of the triangle to become zero, but as we saw earlier the area does not depend on $x$. So, what is the area of the $\Delta pqr$ when $x$ approaches $\infty$?

If the area is constant in $x$, then the limit of the area is also constant in $x$. The limit of constant functions is the constant that defines the function independently of where $x$ approaches.

It's always $\frac12 bh$. What you're asking is a bit like saying, "let $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$. What happens to $n\cdot f(n)$ as $n\to \infty$?" and saying it should be zero because $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$. What you've written has a subtle mistake: you say the angle approaches zero (which is correct) and that the line becomes parallel (which isn't).

The area is also $\frac{1}{2}\sin(\angle p q r) \times b \times q r$ So the angle tends to $0$ but $q r$ tends to $\infty$. The limit of a quantity that tends to $0$ multiplied by a quantity that tends to $\infty$ in not necessarily $0$. In fact $\sin(\angle p q r)  \times q r = h$

@Gribouillis: how about turning your comment into an answer? The question is not bad (possibly a duplicate, but I can't find it): if the angle approaches $0$, wouldn't the triangle "collapse?

@Taladris Done, I turned the comment into an answer.

The area is also $\frac{1}{2}\sin(\angle pqr)\cdot b\cdot qr$ So the angle tends to 0 but $qr$ tends to $\infty$. The limit of a quantity that tends to 0 multiplied by a quantity that tends to $\infty$ in not necessarily 0. In fact $\sin(\angle pqr)\cdot qr=h$
